# Making tree using KMeans

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I'm having a bug that I can't seem to figure out. This is more of a algorithmic style question than it is anything about KMeans.

For context I'm trying to subdivide my data using KMeans iteratively until the number of data points in a cluster is less than 1000. Suppose my data is this:

```py
np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.randn(100000, 768)
```

And a single node looks like this (but I'm open for suggestions):

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name: str, mean: np.array, children: [List[Any]] = []):
        self.name = name
        self.mean = mean
        self.children = children
```

My clustering algorithm is this, and **I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with recursion**.

```py
def cluster(idx: np.array, parent: Optional[Node]=None, parent_label: str=""):
    kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=K)
    kmeans.fit(data[idx])
    labels[idx] = np.array(
        [
            parent_label + ">" + str(label) 
            for label in kmeans.labels_
        ]
    )

    for label, count in Counter(labels[idx]).items():
        kmeans_idx = int(label.rsplit(">", maxsplit=1)[-1])
        node = Node(
            label,
            kmeans.cluster_centers_[kmeans_idx]
        )
        if count > 1000:
            cluster(labels == label, node, label)
        parent.children.append(node)
```

however running the following I end up with the length of the children being the same regardless of which index.

```py
head_node = Node("head", 0)
labels = np.array(["" for _ in range(len(data))], dtype=object)
idx = labels == ""
cluster(idx, head_node)

print(len(head_node.children), len(head_node.children[2].children))
# gives 1060, 1060
```

### Edit 1:

So the imports are:

```py
from typing import Any, Optional
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
```

you should be able to run everything after this.

With regards to how am I using KMeans to make a tree, the idea is if a cluster is too big (>1000 elements), further split that into smaller cluster by reapplying kmeans.

Comment: *"This is more of a algorithmic style question than it is anything about KMeans."* I have no idea what you mean by this sentence. The k-means algorithm **is** an algorithm.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how you use k-means to build a tree? The goal of k-means is to split the data into groups, not into a tree. Perhaps you're interested in some form of hierarchical clustering instead?

Comment: Also, could you please provide a [mre]? In particular, what is `MiniBatchKMeans`? Is this an import from scikit-klearn that you didn't specify in your code snippet? Or code that you wrote yourself? If it is an import, can you please specify the import, and link to the documentation?

Comment: Hope this clears things up.